# How to make DIV tags accessible based on SharePoint role?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security

We have 3 DIV tags in master page (so, available to all pages on site).

DIV 1: Employee

DIV 2: Manager

DIV 3: HR

There are 3 groups in SharePoint:- Employee, Manager and HR.

We want to make the div visible only if the user belongs to the respective group. What is the way to go ahead to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve visibility of web content based on the logged user permissions you can use the SharePoint control [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) .

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID=”SPSecurityTrimmedControl″
 PermissionsString=”PermissionRequiredForViewingContents” runat=”server”>
     <div>Your Content Here<div/>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

As you can see from the above sample using the control is pretty simple: you just wrap the content you want to manage and the control will handle hiding/displaying it, based on the required permission you have specified for the PermissionsString parameter.

There is a problem though. Out of the box the control just supports security trimming based on a permission level. If you need to trim the content based on the current user groups you will need to extend it.

```
public class MySecurityTrimmedControl : SPSecurityTrimmedControl
{
    // Incomplete sample, see comments below


    public override bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Visible && CheckUserIsInGroup();
        }
        set
        {
            base.Visible = value;
        }
    }


    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        if (CheckUserIsInGroup())
        {
            base.Render(output);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea here is to override the Render and Visible properties/methods to include your custom group checking logics. This would give you the ability to perform security trimming based on groups.

Another option worth mentioning is to develop a custom control starting from ground. This way you would be free from the SPSecurityTrimmedControl implementation logic (and based on what Reflector shows that could be a great benefit). Just start from a container (Panel maybe?) and work up from there.

Comment: OK, cool. So I will have to use SPObject model and develop the function "CheckUserIsInGroup()" which will retreive the group of the currently logged in SPUSer and return true/false?..

Comment: Yes, that would be the general idea. Also remember to add a property to the control so you can specify the group/list of groups you want to check against.